# Debugging a custom object in LWC

Tags: debugging

I have a custom object `AP_Customer_Relationship__c`. I use a `<lightning-record-edit-form>` with a custom `onSubmit` functionality. When I try to debug using `event.detail.fields`, it appears as proxy and I cannot see any data. But when I debug using fieldname like `event.detail.fields.Account_ID__c`, I can see the data.
Is there any way to see the whole object's data without using individual fieldnames?

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have use below code and able to get the all the fields.

```
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fields));
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    }
```

[image]